# how to define Root member with PARENT_ID = NULL or PARENT_ID = ID for Parent/Child Dimenssion

Tags: iccube

I am getting an error

> [BUILDER_UNEXPECTED_ERROR] Parent/Child View 'Dim_Parent_Child' without a single root member, at least one root member is mandatory. A Root member is defined with PARENT_ID = NULL or PARENT_ID = ID. location:

Please suggest me to how to define Root member with `PARENT_ID = NULL` or `PARENT_ID = ID` for `Parent/Child` Dimensions

One more thing, It is working fine with Full Load but raising error during  incremental load.
The definition of this view (sorting Columns) is (ID, Parent).
I am using below table data as input to this "sort" view

`ID,Name,Parent
0,Base,NULL
1,Customer Y,18
2,Funding Y,24
3,Credit Risk Sprd,22
4,Liquidity Sprd,24
5,Option Sprd,24
6,Funding Sprd,24
7,Custom Sprd,24
8,Early Termination Adjust,22
9,Risk Free Rate,19
18,Commercial ,22
19,Funding Center ,0
22,PC Contribution,0
23,Transfer Price PC,18
24,Transfer Price,19
25,Product Sprd,24`

Comment: Without the actual data difficult to reply. Please post here an example of table data you are using as input to this "Sort" view and the definition of this view (Sorting Columns, ...). You can create a simple schema with an in-memory table for this test case.

Comment: updated table data detail

Answer (score 0):

With incremental load this view does not work as it is not going to see all the rows: only new rows will are sent to the view and therefore the root will be missing.

Workaround: as it seems you're creating a dimension with this table (& view), you can set the incr. load strategy of this table to FULL_LOAD. Existing members won't be created.

Hope tha helps.

Comment: Thanks Marc.it is working now after apply workaround